# Web Audio: Change gain value before oscillator starts

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I just noticed that it seems not possible to change the `gain.value` of a `gainNode` with the method `setValueAtTime()` or `setValueCurveAtTime()` when there is no oscillator connected or when the oscillator has not started yet.

## `setValueAtTime` after that the oscillator starts

For instance in this case, `setValueAtTime` will work as expected:

```
var context = new AudioContext();

var gain = context.createGain();
gain.connect(context.destination);

var osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 300;
osc.connect(gain);

osc.start();

gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 1);
```

The oscillator starts and the gain is `1` for 1 second. Then `gain.gain.value` will move to `0`.

## `setValueAtTime` before that the oscillator starts

However if we set the gain with `setValueAtTime` before the oscillator starts

```
var context = new AudioContext();

var gain = context.createGain();
gain.connect(context.destination);

var osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 300;
osc.connect(gain);

osc.start(context.currentTime + 1);

gain.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
```

The `gain.gain.value` will stay to 1.

## Set `gain.gain.value` without `setValueAtTime`

What is strange is that this behaviour is not seen if we set the gain directly

```
var context = new AudioContext();

var gain = context.createGain();
gain.connect(context.destination);

var osc = context.createOscillator();
osc.frequency.value = 300;
osc.connect(gain);

osc.start(context.currentTime + 1);

gain.gain.value = 0;
```

The gain value will always stay to 0.

Comment: When I played around with the API I recall having to connect the oscillator to `gain.gain` (`osc.connect(gain.gain)`), that probably doesn't have anything to do with the problem and I'm not completely sure, but you could try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Chrome, then this is probably a [bug in Chrome](http://crbug.com/647974).  Chrome actually returns the computed value in the getter, but if a node doesn't have an input but is still connected to the destination, the AudioParam automations aren't run.  They should be, and the values can be inspected with the `.value` getter.

Answer (score 0):

AudioParam.value isn't a computed value - i.e., it won't tell you the current value of what the gain really *IS*, just what the AudioParam.value was last set to.  (cf https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-value).  If you want to know what the current value of the AudioParam truly is, you'd need to route it to an audio node and collect the data (e.g. via a scriptprocessor).  In your first example, I don't think gain.gain.value should go 0.

The actual value of an AudioParam at any given point in time can be affected not only by the scheduler and the .value, but also by nodes connect()ed to the AudioParam; it would be expensive to compute those values constantly and port them back to the AudioParam.

Comment: Thank for your answer! Interesting, I thought that `.value` corresponded actually to the current value. But how can I change the value of a gain node before connection or before oscillator has started (if it is possible)?

Comment: On the other hand, see https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/318#issuecomment-248006232, which basically says it should return the computed value.  And since the spec also says the `.value` setter is the same as `setValueAtTime`, you wouldn't be able to examine the value ever, if it wasn't the computed value.

Comment: Well you tell me - you're the editor now.  :)  But the spec precisely says:  "The effect of setting this attribute is equivalent to calling setValueAtTime() with the current AudioContext's currentTime and the requested value. Subsequent accesses to this attribute's getter will return the same value."  That just means a set of .value has to have the same effect as setValueAtTime, and if you've set value, it will return that value (not a subsequent setValueAtTime, or the result of a ramp).  It never says "this is the computed value," and that issue was punted to v2.  :(

Comment: Hmm. I think our intent was that the getter returns the computed value (as Chrome does today) and the `getValueAtTime` was punted to v2.  But, yes, this needs to be clarified.  Having the getter return the value of the setter isn't very useful if the param is automated.